# Convert provided string as Smarty template

Tags: php, templates, smarty, smarty-plugins

I am new to smarty template

There is one crazy requirement where I need to convert provided smarty code as a string into smarty template.

Let me explain

1) In page post from user I will get the smarty template which they have typed in textarea
eg.

```
{if '%%loyaltyPoints%%' >=1000}  
 Thanks for being a Gold member!  
{elseif '%%loyaltyPoints%%' < 1000 and '%%loyaltyPoints%%' > 500}  
 Thanks for being a Silver member!  
{else}  
 Thanks for being a Bronze member!  
{/if}
```

2) This will be get in php post -- I want to pass this code to template and execute there

3) ie. This dynamic code should generate in template and the passed value '%%cf_loyaltyPoints%%' need to be compared in `if` `else` conditions and specific output is printed.

I have tried using `$smarty->fetch('string:'.$template_string);` with no success.

Please suggest any better way

Comment: Are you replacing %%loyaltyPoints%% with the value before passing it to fetch?

Comment: @Borgtex Yes that can be changed with actual value

Comment: So what do you mean with "with no success"? is the output wrong, it returns an error...? I tried the code and it works for me.

Comment: can you add your code as answer?

Comment: It wouldn't make a lot of sense, as it is the same code you posted.

Comment: Got your point the output comes in stored variable. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110518/discussion-between-mujaffars-and-borgtex).